# Падает : "Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration." Я хочу использовать свой метод из репозитория, не выходит

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, repository

SpringBootApplication:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.repository")
public class WeatherAppApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Service Implementation:

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.model.Weather;
import com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service

public class WeatherServiceImplementation implements WeatherService {
    @Autowired
    private WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Weather> findAllWeather() {
        return weatherRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Weather getWeatherByLast_updated(String last_updated) {
        return weatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(last_updated);
    }

    @Override
    public Weather addWeatherOnCurrentDate(Weather weather) {
        return weatherRepository.save(weather);
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "weather")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Weather {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "pressure_mb")
    private float pressure_mb;
    @Column(name = "wind_mph")
    private float wind_mph;
    @Column(name = "temperature_celsius")
    private float temp_c;
    @Column(name = "humidity")
    private int humidity;
    @Column(name = "condition")
    private String condition;
    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;
    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private String last_updated;

    public Weather() {

    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Weather;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface WeatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather, Integer> {

    Weather getWeatherByLast_updated(String last_updated);
    //Weather getWeatherById(int id);
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.Weather;
import com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.WeatherService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class WeatherController {
    @Autowired
    private WeatherService weatherService;
    @Autowired
    private WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private String url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=267da6ee01ec4e0a95a162121232003&q=Minsk&aqi=no";

    private double temp_c;
    private String location;
    private double wind_mph;
    private double pressure_mb;
    private int humidity;
    private String last_updated;
    private String condition;


    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello from controller";
    }

    @GetMapping("/allWeathers")
    public List<Weather> getAllWeathers() {
        return weatherService.findAllWeather();
    }

    /*@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Weather getWeatherById(@PathVariable  int id) {
        return weatherRepository.getWeatherById(id);
    }*/

    @GetMapping("/{last_updated}")
    public Weather getWeatherOnCurrentDateByLast_Updated(@PathVariable("last_updated") String last_updated) {
        return weatherService.getWeatherByLast_updated(last_updated);
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", value = "/addWeather")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Weather addNewWeather(@RequestBody Weather weather) {
        Weather weather1 = new Weather();
        weather1.setLocation(location);
        weather1.setHumidity(humidity);
        weather1.setPressure_mb((float) Math.ceil(pressure_mb));
        weather1.setWind_mph((float) Math.ceil(wind_mph));
        weather1.setTemp_c((float) Math.ceil(temp_c));
        weather1.setCondition(condition);
        weather1.setLast_updated(last_updated);

        weatherRepository.save(weather1);

        return weatherService.addWeatherOnCurrentDate(weather1);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {

        return args -> {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String resp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(resp);

            JsonNode locationNode = root.path("location");
            if (!locationNode.isMissingNode()) {
                location = locationNode.path("region").asText();

                System.out.println("name : " + locationNode.path("name").asText());
                System.out.println("region : " + locationNode.path("region").asText());
            }

            JsonNode currentNode = root.path("current");
            if (!currentNode.isMissingNode()) {
                temp_c = currentNode.path("temp_c").asDouble();
                wind_mph = currentNode.path("wind_mph").asDouble();
                pressure_mb = currentNode.path("pressure_mb").asDouble();
                humidity = currentNode.path("humidity").asInt();
                last_updated = currentNode.path("last_updated").asText();
                condition = currentNode.path("condition").path("text").asText();

                System.out.println("temperature in celsius: " + currentNode.path("temp_c").asText());
                System.out.println("wind mph: " + currentNode.path("wind_mph").asText());
                System.out.println("pressure_mb: " + currentNode.path("pressure_mb").asText());
                System.out.println("humidity: " + currentNode.path("humidity").asText());
                System.out.println("current date: " + currentNode.path("last_updated").asText());
                System.out.println("condition: " + currentNode.path("condition").path("text").asText());

            }

        };
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WeatherApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/weather
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
```

LOG:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'weatherService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherServiceImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'weatherRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WeatherAppApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at com.example.demo.WeatherAppApplication.main(WeatherAppApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherServiceImplementation': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'weatherRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WeatherAppApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WeatherAppApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.model.Weather com.example.demo.repository.WeatherRepository.getWeatherByLast_updated(java.lang.String)! No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:259) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'last' found for type 'Weather'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:438) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:414) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:367) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
```

Comment: Добавьте содержимое pox.xml. Возможно проблема именно в неподключенной зависимости.

Comment: JPA-репозитории вы включили, а датасурс сконфигурили? В application.yml например?

Comment: Сконфигурировано в application , добавила этот файл

Comment: 1. Самое главное не показали: логи. 2. Не вижу проперти spring.datasource.driver-class-name : driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver (как пример). Поточнее смогу сказать как только полностью логи увижу. Обычно ценная информация (первопричина) как раз в конце лога после слов `Caused by`.

Comment: методы стандартные работают и база меняется . как только создаю свой метод в репозитории и пытаюсь его использовать все падает.

Answer (score 0):

Для метода  Weather findWeatherByLast_updated (String last_updated); было плохой идеей писать имя переменной с нижним . спринг видел ее как last)))поменяла имя и все заработало